# Best way to connect react and express

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I'm new to the node environment and would like to know what is the best way to connect a node app running express server to use reactjs Components.

I've seen many tutorials and there doesn't seem to be a single way, can you guys recommend the best practices for this please.

Comment: This question is too open ended, and requiring of much opinion, for a typical Stackoverflow question. But I'll bite... don't worry about best. Just write a typical client side React app which sends ajax requests to Express.

Comment: What about the initial routes ect? How do I wire those up so they're using react from the get go.

Comment: A typical React application is a SPA (single page application). You only need one route in express for serving index.html, all your other routes should just handle database stuff.

Comment: Personally, I don't even serve any static files from Express. I use Express for my database API, and I serve my React front end the same way you would serve a static html page (apache / nginx / express etc)

Comment: Have an example or link?

Comment: sure, here's a repo of mine. https://github.com/alex-wilmer/rater

Comment: cheers, thanks boss.

Comment: "and there doesn't seem to be a single way". You are right because its based on factors like if there's already an existing API, whether the API is served off from a different server and so on.